# Is it ok to flash a bios from within Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, upgrade, flash, bios

I remember back in the day when you had to boot the computer and flash outside of windows.  However, the manufacturer's site doesn't say anything about doing this.  So is it ok to just run the flash program from within Windows 7?

[This is where I downloaded the BIOS update](http://www.gigabyte.com.tw/Support/Motherboard/BIOS_Model.aspx?ProductID=3156)

Comment: Answer: No, especially if the motherboard, like an old one, has no easy recovery methods.

Answer (score 2):

Last time I did this, with an ASUS motherboard and Windows 7, the flashing tool crashed in the middle of the flash operation. Bricked motherboard! I had to buy a new motherboard (and I still don't know what to do with the bricked one).

I strongly recommend against flashing inside the OS. You'd better use other means: most recent motherboards support flashing from a USB key nowadays.

Comment: @Phenom: Make sure you also have available your CURRENT BIOS for flashing as safeguard, in case the new BIOS fails to work for any reason whatsoever.

Comment: I had a failed flashing the other day; but I was able to put a BIOS image on a flash drive, boot into the BIOS and use the M-Flash option to reflash the image and restore the mobo to working order.

Answer (score 1):

There is no risk when you flash from windows, you have to stop all running programs, and do not power off while updating the bios.

I flash from windows from the beginning (there are several years), I flash lots of  motherboards asus, gigabyte,biostar, asrock and there was no problem.

So, yes just run the flash problem without any concern.

Comment: I agree that this shouldn't be a risk, if you avoid anything that could interfere

Comment: “things that could interfere” being in particular AV and other dodgy ‘security’ software that sinks its hooks deep into the OS and messes everything about.